# How to access a model attribute across all templates?

Tags: python, html, django

I have a model team with attribute name:

```
class Team(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
```

I want to put the team name in the header of the website, as in my template language would be something like:

```
{% if team.name %}
<h1>{{ team.name }}</h1>
{% endif %}
```

However the name only displays if I'm on a view that makes a query on the team model. So I guess I need to have that query available across all views/templates. What is the best way of going about this?

Comment: You can use a *context processor* for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variables you want to set for *every* template call (well you do not have to use them *per se*, but typically it pays off when you use these in nearly every template), can be set with *context processors*.

Context processors are functions that take as input a `request` parameter, and return a dictionary that maps variable names (so strings) to the content that the parameter should carry, like:

```
# myapp/context_processors.py

def first_team(request):
    return { 'first_team': Team.objects.first() }
```

We can store these under an app (it does not matter which one, but typically the one that is the closests semantically to what the context processor is doing).

Next we can register our context processor in `settings.py`. We can alter the `TEMPLATES` settings, and register the context processor:

```
# settings.py

TEMPLATES = [
    {

        # ...

        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                # ...
                'myapp.context_processors.first_team',
                # ...
            ],
        },

        # ...

    },
]
```

In fact it is quite likely that you already have some context processors without ever noticing.

Next you can use `{{ first_team }}` (and derived products) in every template that you render (without overriding the settings when rendering). Note that you have to be careful about giving variables a name in context processors, since these can *override* existing ones.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for that Willem. Got it integrated and working.